# Embed web sites/frames into VF pages/Dashboards?

Tags: iframe

I am trying to figure out a way to embed a web site onto a Salesforce dashboard by using a Visualforce component on a Dashbaord. I'm currently using an iframe approach. However, it is only appearing as a tiny window just like every other Dashboard component such as Reports, Charts etc.

Is there a way to give the component a bigger window on the dashboard so maybe it could take up the entire width (or close to it).

Should I be using a the plain web link somehow instead of the iframe ?

Should I not even be using Dashboards ? Is there a better way to display a Visualforce page which is for this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The best you can do is to keep only one column and only one dashboard component. Why do you have to use this on dashboard though?

Comment: I suppose I don't absolutely have to have it on a dashboard. Do you have a better suggestion ? I'm assuming VF needs to be involved ? If so, then the only other potential solution I can think of would be to have a custom tab which displays the VF page ?

Comment: you can have VF page on its own. can create a VF tab to have it accessible by users

Comment: @Oleksiy - yes, I have tried that but I hate how it opens in a whole new tab. Maybe if it opened in a new tab it would be a little better. Also, I don't know how to make it wider when I put it into a tab.

Also - I've tried putting it into a single column dashboard, but I can't get a dashboard to only 1 column. It looks like I am forced to keep at least 2 columns because it won't let me remove the 2nd column. I click on it and it doesn't go away.